# How to get the ChoiceField value from a form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to get the chosen email-id from a drop down list made from ChoiceField. I have written a code but apparently it is not working.
How do I do it ?

Here is my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def assign(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        assign_now = AssignTask(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if assign_now.is_valid():
            task_title = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('title')
            task_description = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('desc')
            assign_email = assign_now.cleaned_data('assign_to')
            assign_email = dict(AssignTask.fields['assign_to'].choices)[assign_email]
            user_details = User.objects.get(email=assign_email)
            t = Task(title=task_title, description=task_description, assigned_to=user_details)
            t.save()
            return HttpResponse('<h2>Successfully assigned task</h2>')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h2><Task assignment failed/h2>')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h2>Request method error</h2>')
```

Here is my **forms.py**

```
class AssignTask(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    assign_to = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=[]))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AssignTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/assignment/todoapp/views.py" in assign
  118.             assign_email = assign_now.cleaned_data('assign_to')

Exception Type: TypeError at /assign
Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error traceback, We can understand, you are missing a **`.get()`** function

so, try this,

```
assign_email = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('assign_to')
```

instead of

```
 assign_email = assign_now.cleaned_data('assign_to')
```

---

complete view function

```
@login_required
def assign(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        assign_now = AssignTask(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if assign_now.is_valid():
            task_title = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('title')
            task_description = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('desc','Sample Description')
            assign_email = assign_now.cleaned_data.get('assign_to')
            user_details = User.objects.get(email=assign_email)
            t = Task(title=task_title, description=task_description, assigned_to=user_details)
            t.save()
            return HttpResponse('<h2>Successfully assigned task</h2>')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h2><Task assignment failed/h2>')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h2>Request method error</h2>')
```